# microtime to standard date format

Tags: php, date, milliseconds, microtime

I Have some values which are milliseconds since epoch i.e. `microtime(true)` in my MySQL database these are got out as strings I need to convert them over to a standard PHP date()

```
$updated = 1349697975.9381;
$nUpdated = date($updated, "l jS F \@\ g:i a");
```

This is returning a blank string, anyone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be  `date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )`

You got the position wrong

```
   $nUpdated = date("l jS F \@ g:i a",$updated);
```

Output

```
Monday 8th October @ 2:06 pm
```

Comment: I don't understand the second backslash, what does it escape? :) +1

Comment: Mihai Iorga was taling about `\@\` @Justin Erswell

Answer (score 0):

You have the arguments to [`date()`](http://php.net/date) backwards (the timestamp is the second parameter).

Try updating to:

```
$nUpdated = date("l jS F \@ g:i a", $updated);
```